# Ambiguous overloaded call when compiling for ESP32

Tags: c++, opencv, esp32

*Disclaimer: I haven't done C/C++ in ages and have decided to dive into the deeper end here.*

I'm attempting to build [esp32-opencv](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv) which is basically a version of OpenCV [with some necessary changes](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv/blob/master/esp32/doc/detailed_build_procedure.md#modified-files-for-opencv-to-compile-and-run) for the ESP32.

I'm seeing the following error on `make` that isn't referenced in that project:

```
esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:3537:107: error: call of overloaded 'softdouble(int)' is ambiguous
 3537 | static const float64_t exp_prescale = float64_t::fromRaw(0x3ff71547652b82fe) * float64_t(1 << EXPTAB_SCALE);
      |                                                                                                           ^
In file included from esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:68:
esp32-opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/softfloat.hpp:257:14: note: candidate: 'cv::softdouble::softdouble(double)'
  257 |     explicit softdouble( const double a ) { Cv64suf s; s.f = a; v = s.u; }
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:248:1: note: candidate: 'cv::softdouble::softdouble(int64_t)'
  248 | softdouble::softdouble( const  int64_t a ) { *this =  i64_to_f64(a); }
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:247:1: note: candidate: 'cv::softdouble::softdouble(int32_t)'
  247 | softdouble::softdouble( const  int32_t a ) { *this =  i32_to_f64(a); }
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:246:1: note: candidate: 'cv::softdouble::softdouble(uint64_t)'
  246 | softdouble::softdouble( const uint64_t a ) { *this = ui64_to_f64(a); }
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:245:1: note: candidate: 'cv::softdouble::softdouble(uint32_t)'
  245 | softdouble::softdouble( const uint32_t a ) { *this = ui32_to_f64(a); }
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from esp32-opencv/modules/core/src/softfloat.cpp:68:
esp32-opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/softfloat.hpp:232:5: note: candidate: 'cv::softdouble::softdouble(const cv::softdouble&)'
  232 |     softdouble( const softdouble& c) { v = c.v; }
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Further up in the code it has: `#define EXPTAB_SCALE 6` so the complaint seems to be about `float64_t(1 << EXPTAB_SCALE)` = `float64_t(1 << 6)` = `float64_t(64)`?

The definitions all refer to `[u]int[size]_t` and none for `int`. I am building this with the `xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++` compiler. The [esp32-opencv project](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv) shows that it used `xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++` (the difference being `esp-2022r1-11.2.0` vs `esp-2019r2-8.2.0`).

I don't have the knowledge to formulate a good guess on why this isn't working with the ESP32 build setup vs compiling it for my 64bit Ubuntu machine. Why would the call not be ambiguous in the latter case, but with the ESP32 build it can't decide which method to use?

If I *did* have to guess I would think there is some difference in how integer types are being handled in the `xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0` compiler used in the Github project vs the `xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0`, but I also have no idea how to check that.

Comment: It seems `int != int32_t` in `xtensa-esp32-elf-g++`. Is the target 16-bit arch?

Comment: best contact the authors/maintainers of that "esp32-opencv" port.